# GroupBy and Sum operation in result of Union in Laravel 5

Tags: database, laravel-5

In **Laravel 5** how can I make a *SUM*, and *GroupBy* operations after an Union?
I have a result that it's an union of 2 querys (from different tables), I have the data correctly, but after the union I want to *Sum* a column, and *GroupBy* the result.thanks

**EDITED:**

```
$minutos=DB::table('tutorias as tut')
       ->join('usuarios as usu','usu.id','=','tut.profesor_id')
        ->join('perfiles as perfil','perfil.id','=','usu.perfil_id')
        ->whereNotNull('tut.Hora_entrada')
        ->select(DB::raw(' Sum(0) AS inasistencias'),'perfil.nombres',DB::raw('sum(tut."Hora_entrada"-tut.hora_inicio) as minutos'))
        ->addSelect('usu.id as id')
        ->groupBy('usu.id','nombres');

    $pro=DB::table('tutorias as tut')
        ->join('usuarios as usu','usu.id','=','tut.profesor_id')
        ->join('perfiles as perfil','perfil.id','=','usu.perfil_id')
        ->where('fecha','<',$dt) 
        ->whereNull('tut.Hora_entrada') 
        ->select(DB::raw('count(tut.id) as inasistencias'),'perfil.nombres',DB::raw(' Sum(tut.hora_inicio-tut.hora_inicio) AS minutos'))
        ->addSelect('usu.id as id')
        ->groupBy('usu.id','nombres')
        ->union($minutos)
        ->orderBy('inasistencias', 'asc')
        ->get();
```

Then, I want to sum the *inasistencias* and *minutos* column and group for every user

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? It would be good if you could provide some kind of example of what you're doing - are working with models or is it a raw query builder?

In general what you want is to wrap your union results into select operation which would handle SUM operation.

Comment: @KaneCohen exactly, I'm using Raw. I edited and added the query

Comment: The more I see frameworks' ways of creating SQL, the more I feel that it's better to just write clean SQL and ask frameworks to execute it.